# Download file from Flask application running in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm making a Flask application which runs in a Docker container. Everything works fine so far, but now I want to make a GET method, which should return a file to be downloaded by the user. For this, I've tried the Flask functions `send_file` and `send_from_directory`. They both work when I run my application as is, but as soon as I put it in a Docker container, things stop working.

If I use `send_file`, I get a `file not found` error, although I can call `print(os.path.isfile)` using the same file path, and it will show up.

If I used `send_from_directory` using the correct path and file name then I get instead a 404 error.

Again, this is only when running from a Docker container. Could it be a permission issue?

Example of method:

```
class DownloadLog(Resource):
    def get(self):
        print(os.path.isfile('logfile.log')  # Returns 'True'
        return send_from_directory('.', 'logfile.log')
```

Comment: A permission issue would throw a 403 Forbidden or unauthorized and not a 404. So that is probably not the case

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue and I fixed it by passing the full file path instead of the relative path when the app is running in a container.

For example, when I'm running only flask, I can use something like:

```
send_from_directory(
    current_app.config["DOWNLOAD_FOLDER"], filename.jpg, as_attachment=True
)
```

However, if running the app inside a container, I need to change it to:

```
send_from_directory(
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), current_app.config["DOWNLOAD_FOLDER"]),
    filename.jpg,
    as_attachment=True,
)
```

Basically `os.getcwd()` is the app root folder defined inside the Dockerfile or the docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly a year late to answer this though,

When you execute flask_application as is and use `send_from_directory(directory/path, filename, as_attachment=True)`, it sends files from your `HOST OS` file system (Windows, Linux, macOS).

When you execute flask_application inside docker container and use `send_from_directory(directory/path, filename, as_attachment=True)`, it sends files from your `WORKDIR (/app)`. As flask couldn't find the file in the WORKDIR, it reports 404.

If you want this to work in docker, you can `ADD or COPY` the files that you want the user to download and then use their path in `send_from_directory`, or you can use volumes also.

Hope It Helps!

PS: Today I went through the same!